# Use c++ uint8_t * from c# using SWIG

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I have a functiong which look somethink like this:

```
virtual int64_t Read(uint8_t* buffer, int64_t bufferLength) = 0
```

which we want to overide (as this is an abstract class) and implament from c# code (using director). using

```
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%apply uint8_t INPUT[] {uint8_t* buffer}
```

I was able to get a c# translation with the signature of

```
public virtual long Read(byte[] buffer, long bufferLength)
```

which is what I wanted. but when trying to compile the SWIG code we are getting errors as follows:

```
 error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'unsigned char *'
 note: Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
```

because of this lins in the generated swig cc file:

```
 int64_t c_result = SwigValueInit< int64_t >() ;
 long long jresult = 0 ;
 unsigned char* jbuffer = 0 ;
 long long jbufferLength  ;
 long long jbufferOffset  ;

 if (!swig_callbackRead__SWIG_0) {
    throw Swig::DirectorPureVirtualException("mip::Stream::Read");
  } else {
    jbuffer = (void *) buffer; <========= FAIL LINE
    jbufferLength = bufferLength;
    jresult = (long long) swig_callbackRead__SWIG_0(jbuffer, jbufferLength);
    c_result = (int64_t)jresult; 
  }
```

How can I tell SWIG not to cast to (void *)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the directorin typemap isn't quite right here. I think this should be sufficient to fix it, on the line after your `%apply` directive:

```
%typemap(directorin) uint8_t *buffer "$input = $1;"
```

The above typemap only matches non-const `uint8_t*` parameters named `buffer`. We can make that much more generic if we want to, e.g.:

```
%typemap(directorin) SWIGTYPE * "$input = $1;"
```

Will match anything that doesn't have a better match, const or non-const alike. I can't figure out why that isn't the default anyway, so there's a risk here that it might break something elsewhere that I've not thought of, so you may prefer to continue being selective in where this gets applied..

You can also do something like:

```
%typemap(directorin) SWIGTYPE * "$input = ($1_ltype)$1;"
```

Or add another variant:

```
%typemap(directorin) const SWIGTYPE * "$input = const_cast<$1_ltype>($1);"
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked for this fundtion, but I have the same problem for `virtual int64_t Write(const uint8_t* buffer, int64_t bufferLength)= 0` which still have the same problem.
also - can you please explane how does it help?

Comment: @AssafSapir you can apply that to const things too: `%typemap(directorin) const uint8_t *buffer "$input = $1;"`, but I've edited the answer with a much more generic option as well.

Comment: Applying the generic way indeed work for both, but for the write function it's now complains about `cannot convert from 'const uint8_t *' to 'unsigned char *'`

Comment: @AssafSapir added another few variations on the SWIGTYPE one. If you use the `const SWIGTYPE *` form you'll also need to keep the non-const one.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from compiler is quite plain. You should explicitly convert `void *` to `unsigned char *`.

Try:

```
jresult = (long long) swig_callbackRead__SWIG_0(static_cast<unsigned char *>(jbuffer), jbufferLength);
```

Comment: but how do I tell SWIG to create this? the cc file is automaticlly generated by SWIG

Comment: @AssafSapir Is that possible to modify the generated cc file?